# Get the field names in elasticsearch where search value matches

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to get the field names where my search criteria matches. I have used **lowercase_keyword analyser**.

I tried using highlight query but it only works for exact matches.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "cosmic"
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "*" : { }
        },
       "require_field_match": false
    }
}
```

I want a solution so that I can also get field names of nested fields and partial matching fields apart from exact matching fields.